# What's the name of the theory that the player with the most options has the advantage?

Tags: terminology, combinatorial-game-theory

A long time ago, I remember reading about a theory that sounds like this:

> Players A and B have access to options X and Y. Player A also has access to option Z. Player A is, at worst, equal to and, at best, at an advantage to player B.

Ok, so that was poorly worded. Let me put it another way:

> Having more options available to you in a two player game can't possibly hurt you.**

**Example**

Player A can attack from both sides. Player B must attack from the left. If attacking to the left is the best choice, then both players are equal. If attacking from the right is the best choice, then Player A has a distinct advantage. Player A is either tied or winning. Player B is either tied or losing.

Can anyone tell me the name of the theory I described?

** *"... can't possibly hurt you"* assumes optimal play from both players. It's not always the case the player with the most options will use them wisely. Intuition tells us that sometimes having too many options can make it difficult for the player to find the best one. Just assume that both players are making the best choices when this theory applies.

Comment: Indeed, if we don't assume optimal play, then the result could easily be the exact opposite! Player B only has access to option X, and Player A has option X and another, worse option. Player B is in the better position.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually part of [formal game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory), or just a theory about games?

Comment: To readers: this question has spurred me to open the following meta question: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/the-game-theory-tag-is-consistently-misused-how-do-we-resolve-this

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I'm not well-versed in formal game theory. When I wrote the question, I felt like a theory that relates "options available" to "advantage" should fall into that realm. Since it was the [tag:identify-this-game] tag that led me to even ask this question here, I thought it would be appropriate to retag with a brand new tag called [tag:identify-this-theory].

Comment: I suspect this "theory" isn't much of a thing. It's pretty trivial: if my opponent doesn't have any options I don't have, then they don't have a better option than my best.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Others have voiced similar suspicions. You may be correct, but there isn't a tag called [tag:identify-this-theory-if-it-exists], and so we work with what we've got.

Comment: That comment would mean more if not for the fact that you also invented the tag that you actually used. And I'm not saying that the question is mis-tagged. I'm arguing that a question asking for the *name* of a trivial set theory result doesn't belong here at all, even if you use the words "player" and "option".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial set theory result with the word "player" substituted in. It is not related to any particular board or card game.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I don't see how triviality plays a role here. I asked for the proper terminology so that I can use it (if it exists). This is the second time someone on this site has misinterpreted "I don't think a good answer exists." as "This question is off-topic." If all you saw in my question was "I have two sets, and one of them is a subset of the other.", then I think you missed the point of the question.

Comment: OK then, let's ignore the triviality aspect. Your question is still of the class "Here is a description of <something vaguely related to games>. Is there a word for it?" I don't think that belongs here.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I can respect the view that the question is only loosely related to games. I hope others don't feel the same way.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Now that my question is on the verge of being closed due to your campaign on meta that has drawn larger than average attention to my question, I feel entitled to further explanation. It sounds like you view my question as "Set A is *larger than* set B and also *contains* set B. What is that called?" Now consider this: If talking about how many nails are in your leg, larger is worse. If talking about options in a game with optimal play, larger is better. Therefore, the context is *necessary*. Your oversimplification of my question is therefore inaccurate!

Comment: I'm sorry, my campaign on meta? You can see from my user profile that I have had no activity on meta for months. "Better" and "worse" don't matter, either way the question is about the same mathematical fact. Regardless, that's not why this question should be closed. It should be closed because *it's not about specific board or card games* and is therefore not on-topic on this site.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Your campaign on meta was both good and helpful. I was merely pointing to the fact that it drew extra attention to the question, and therefore a higher number of close votes if you assume a constant rate of close votes per viewer. Are you saying that every question on this site must be about a *specific* board or card game, and that questions about games in general are not welcome here? If so, then I sorely misinterpreted the topic of this stack exchange.

Comment: I seriously have no idea what meta campaign you are talking about. In any case, the [on-topic help page](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "For a question to be on topic, it must relate to a game that is on topic."

Comment: @murgatroid99 You collected like 7 questions into one post on meta and then called for them to all be retagged. I call that a campaign, but you want to argue linguistics so we'll call it a "thing". Moved discussion to meta: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1167/6692

Comment: @Rusher You've made a mistake - **it was me** who opened that meta topic. And, point of order: it's not a campaign, just a tag cleanup, which is a pretty common thing to do on SE sites. That and your question has been sitting on the front page for days; I doubt the meta topic was a big contributor to the close votes.

Comment: I'm not sure this theory, as you initially state it, is meaningful for most kinds of turn based game. Consider a chess board where white has a rook and a king, and black has a queen and a king. White goes first, and uses his rook to capture the queen. In the following turns, he will force a checkmate. Even though black had more options in the starting state, he loses.

Comment: This is in fact a well-established theorem in Conbinatorial Game Theory; it's a piece of proving the so-called _Simplest Form Theorem_.  If I remember when I get home I can chase down proper references, but the canonical source is the book _Winning Ways For Your Mathematical Plays_.

Comment: @Kevin In your hypothetical situation, the black player does not actually have all of the options available to the white player. The white player will change the board state before the black player even gets to move, and so the black player's future options are *unknown*. An alternative way to think about it is that the black player only has a single immediate option: Do nothing until the turn ends. In other words, your assumption that black had the option to move his Queen, or would ever have that option in the future, is false.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I had similar thoughts while writing that comment. So, generally, for turn based games where the active player can make a choice that limits the other player's options, it's very hard to characterize both players as "having all the same options, except one option that only one player always has", since both player's options fluctuate up and down depending on whose turn it is.

Comment: I happened to come across this Question a few days ago, and then entirely unrelatedly came across this paragraph in the wikipedia article on the GameTheory of the game Chicken: `One tactic in the game is for one party to signal their intentions convincingly before the game begins. For example, if one party were to ostentatiously disable their steering wheel just before the match, the other party would be compelled to swerve.` **`This shows that, in some circumstances, reducing one's own options can be a good strategy.`** Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_(game)#Pre-commitment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a [strategy-stealing argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument). It's often used to prove that one side of a game has an advantage, even if optimal strategy is not known. As a broad example, consider a game with the following properties:

- It is a turn-based game
- The starting positions are identical except Player A goes first
- Player A has the option of skipping the first turn

Assuming optimal play, the first player cannot be at a disadvantage. The proof is a strategy-stealing argument: Any hypothetical strategy that Player B could use to get an advantage could be countered by Player A just skipping the first turn and then using that exact strategy.

Answer (score -3):

Is this principle even true? Consider the following game:

A, B, and C, are dividing $60. All players left standing at the end of the game receive an equal split.

Each player may shoot one other player. If a player gets shot twice, that player can no longer participate in the split.

Alternatively, C has the option to shoot another player, and then (after the first shots resolve) shoot both other players twice.

Obviously, the optimal strategy for C is to take the second option, but then the optimal strategy for A and B is to both shoot C (if they don't, they will get nothing). This means that if all players act rationally, A and B will get $30 each and C will get $0.

In other words, C having more options leads to a worse result for C. So the theory isn't even true, which I think is decent evidence that it doesn't have a name, especially given that nobody else who's come here so far has heard of it. :-P

Comment: First, this isn't even an answer. Second, your counterexample involves more than two players. The theory still holds for two players. I edited the question to clarify. I know that it invalidates half of your answer, but it should have been a comment to begin with.

Comment: SE sites don't usually let you comment on questions with only 1 reputation. Is this one different? I know this isn't quite what you were looking for, but I thought it was worth sharing.

Comment: I think the game must also have no hidden information and no randomness. I can elaborate if you're interested.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that this site was any different. If the choice was post in the wrong place, or don't post at all, I would choose the latter. But since you already posted, if you still want to share then I am interested.

Comment: This place doesn't work like a forum - check our [tour] for more information. Answers are expected to answer the question (in this case, what's the theory called?), whereas this just seems to just be discussing the theory itself. You're welcome to discuss that _as part of an answer_ that otherwise answers the question, though.

Comment: This seems like a valid answer to me. If the theory really didn't have a name, what would the correct answer look like? "I read every game theory paper in the world, and none of them had this theory in them"? The next best thing you could do is a probabilistic argument: "theories that aren't true are usually not named; this theory isn't true; therefore, it probably doesn't have a name". (whether his disproof of the theory is correct or not is another matter; even if it wasn't, the post would still be an answer, just a wrong answer.)

Comment: If this player gets shot once, he's going straight to the hospital. I probably shouldn't play games where I can get shot.

Comment: Moderator: This answer passes the bar for being an answer to the question.  It can be downvoted as not useful, but it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: This doesn't pass the bar. At what point is this actually answering the question of what the theory is called? Even if it's an _inaccurate_ or _incorrect_ theory, it still may have a name. If the theory _doesn't_ have a name, there either _is no answer_, or the answer is "it doesn't have one, and I can say that because {insert authoritative citation here}" - so, yes, the answer @Kevin describes is roughly what a correct answer would look like. Not having a name doesn't turn this into an opportunity for this to be a discussion forum.

Comment: I'm not deleting this. Attempting to prove the theory invalid as an argument for why it doesn't exist is a reasonable answer. Whether the proof is any good is a different question. Feel free to vote appropriately.